# Get next available time slot after a certain time in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I am trying to get the next available time slot by checking the list of reserved times in the table. Each reservation can be minimam of 1 hour incrementation and gcan go on all day. So for example, if the room is booked from 9 AM to 10 AM, and from 12 AM to 3 PM and I am trying to get the first available slot after 9 am. It will be 10 am.

I am able to left join on the table and get the room availability but just not the time slots.

Here is my related schema:

**Reservations**

```
res_id | hotel_id | room_id | res_start | res_end
```

**Rooms:**

```
room_id | hotel_id | room_name | room_number
```

Here is the query I have so far:

```
SELECT free_from, free_until
FROM (
  SELECT a.res_end AS free_from,
  (SELECT MIN(c.res_start)
   FROM reservations c
   WHERE c.res_start > a.res_end) as free_until
   and b.res_end > "2019-01-05 11:00:00"
  FROM reservations a
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM reservations b
    WHERE b.res_start > a.res_end
  )
) as d
ORDER BY free_until-free_from
```

But I am getting the wrong time returned from it.

**Expected result:**

```
room_id | room_name | Next available time
1       | "Single"  | 2019-01-05 10:00:00
```

Here is a time_slots table

```
CREATE TABLE time_slots
    (`slot` time);

INSERT INTO time_slots
    (`slot`)
VALUES
    ('00:00:00'),
    ('01:00:00'),
    ('02:00:00'),
    ('03:00:00'),
    ('04:00:00'),
    ('05:00:00'),
    ('06:00:00'),
    ('07:00:00'),
    ('08:00:00'),
    ('09:00:00'),
    ('10:00:00'),
    ('11:00:00'),
    ('12:00:00'),
    ('13:00:00'),
    ('14:00:00'),
    ('15:00:00'),
    ('16:00:00'),
    ('17:00:00'),
    ('18:00:00'),
    ('19:00:00'),
    ('20:00:00'),
    ('21:00:00'),
    ('22:00:00'),
    ('23:00:00');
```

Comment: Why isn't the next available slot at 10am if the previous one ends then?

Comment: @Nick you are correct. I edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery to filter out reservations that are immediately followed by another one ; the aggregated outer query returns the earlier available timeslot for each room.

```
SELECT 
    roo.hotel_id,
    roo.room_id,
    roo.room_name,
    MIN(res.res_end) next_available_time
FROM 
    reservations res
    INNER JOINS rooms roo 
        ON  roo.hotel_id = res.hotel_id 
        AND roo.room_id  = res.room_id
WHERE 
    res.res_end > "2019-01-05 11:00:00"
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM reservations
        WHERE 
            res_start = res.res_end 
            AND hotel_id = res.hotel_id 
            AND room_id  = res.room_id
    ) 
GROUP BY 
    res.hotel_id,
    res.room_id,
    roo.room_name
```

Tested in [this DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n1qG4j5hQk6mdQZokAR2NE/0).

I assumed that both columns `hotel_id` and `room_id` where to be used when joining tables (if `room_id` was enough, that would shorten the query a little).

Comment: The issue is that it doesn't give the correct answer if res.res_end is before any of the reservation for example res.res_end > "2018-01-01 01:00:00"

Comment: So in this case, what do you want to return ? `"2018-01-01 01:00:00"` ?

Comment: 2018-01-01 07:00:00 since that is last available time slot before reservations start at 2018-01-01 08:00:00

Comment: You said you want the **first** available timeslot after a given date. I would expect this to be `2018-01-01 01:00:00`, if the room is not booked at the particular time, no ?

Comment: I am trying to see until WHEN a room can be booked. So I guess it would be until 2018-01-01 08:00:00 and the last bookable slot can be 07:00:00

Comment: Sorry this is unclear ; your OP said : *I am trying to get the next available time slot*, and that's what both answers provided...

Answer (score 1):

I think this query will give you the results you want. It looks for any reservation later than the current time whose `res_end` has no matching `res_start` for another reservation.

```
SELECT rm.room_id, rm.room_name, MIN(re.res_end) AS `available from`
FROM reservations re
LEFT JOIN reservations rs ON rs.hotel_id = re.hotel_id AND rs.room_id = re.room_id AND rs.res_start = re.res_end
JOIN rooms rm ON rm.hotel_id = re.hotel_id
WHERE rs.res_id IS NULL AND re.res_end > NOW()
GROUP BY rm.room_id, rm.room_name
```

Output (for my small [demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b562df974a3cdff046ed0452d2c63e50)):

```
room_id     room_name   available from
1           Single      2019-01-06 10:00
```

**Update**

This query uses a timeslot table to allow for the case where there are no reservations in a room when the time of interest starts:

```
SELECT rm.room_id, rm.room_name,
       MIN(t.slot) AS `available from`
FROM time_slots t
CROSS JOIN rooms rm
LEFT JOIN reservations r ON HOUR(t.slot) BETWEEN HOUR(r.res_start) AND HOUR(r.res_end) - 1 
                        AND DATE(r.res_start) = DATE(@time)
                        AND r.hotel_id = rm.hotel_id
                        AND r.room_id  = rm.room_id
WHERE t.slot > @time AND r.res_id IS NULL
GROUP BY rm.room_id, rm.room_name
ORDER BY rm.room_id
```

You would replace `@time` in this query with your time of interest. I've updated my [demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=60cd353556321cd74f1392afa249521c) to demonstrate the query, you can play with adjusting the `@time` variable to watch it work.

Comment: This is the correct answer but has one caveat. When I set re.res_end > "2019-01-05 08:00:00" for example. It shows 10:00 while it should show 09:00.

Comment: @HeelMega you are correct, it won't show the current time if that is free. That will require some thinking... let me edit my answer

Comment: added a time slot table for you in the question

Comment: @HeelMega I've updated my answer and demo. I think this should do what you want.